# Override url_for globally so that extensions use it as well

Tags: python, flask, flask-assets

I'm trying to override the `url_for` function globally. I want to do this so that I can load my assets from multiple urls to overcome the browser's maximum concurrent connections limit.

I used `app.context_processor` to substitute my own function in templates, but it's not working when used with Flask-Assets.

```
STATIC_URLS = [
    static.1.domain.com,
    static.2.domain.com,
    static.3.domain.com
]

@app.context_processor
def override_url_for():
    return dict(url_for=static_urls)

def static_urls(endpoint, **values):
    if endpoint == 'static':
        filename = values.get('filename', None)
        static_urls = app.config.get('STATIC_URLS', None)
        if filename and static_urls:
            hashed = int(hashlib.md5(filename.encode()).hexdigest(), 16)
            index = hashed % len(static_urls) - 1
            url = static_urls[index]
            url = app.url_map.bind(url)
            return url.build(endpoint, values=values, force_external=True)

    return url_for(endpoint, **values)
```

In the template, `url_for` works correctly, but `ASSET_URL` does not.

```html
{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}
http://static.1.domain.com/static/style.css

{% assets 'style' %}
<link href="{{ ASSET_URL }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
{% endassets %}
http://domain.com/static/style.css
```

How can I make this work in extensions like Flask-Assets?

Comment: You can see how Flask-CDN does it: https://github.com/wichitacode/flask-cdn/blob/master/flask_cdn.py#L7

Comment: Instead of monkey patching the function globally, they override it in `jinja_env` so it will only work in templates. But since it's static files that might be what you want?

Comment: My current solution already works in templates but not when using the external plugin Flask-Assets

Comment: @nathancahill Your link doesn't work and I wanted to check it out.  Does it have a typo in it?

Comment: @DaveScotese Looks like the author of that repo deleted his Github account in the last 4 years. We'll never know what was there.

Comment: It might have been something like this: https://github.com/e-dard/flask-s3/blob/b8c72b40eb38a05135eec36a90f1ee0c96248f72/flask_s3.py#L132